# TweetSharp - Statuses is coming Null

Tags: c#, tweetsharp

Few days before everything is working fine with same code.. but now Statuses is getting null.

```
TwitterSearchResult res = service.Search(new SearchOptions { Q = "#Brazil", Count = 100 });
IEnumerable<TwitterStatus> tweets = res.Statuses;
```

Could you please suggest what I need to do..? Otherwise could you please suggest any other way  to get tweets of particular hashtag..

thanks

Comment: did you authenticate to the service?

Comment: yes I'm authenticating. Same code is working on local machine.. but its not working on client machine..